# Azure table service shared Access Signature not available

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm running Azure SDK June 2012 Sp1 aka the august update. I'm trying to generate a shared signature which will be consumed by a WPF client. The problem is that I'm not able to resolve

```
SharedAccessTablePolicy policy = new SharedAccessTablePolicy()
```

Which assembly should I reference and which version?

/Rasmus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The June 2012 SP1 update is exactly the same as the June 2012 update, just with compatibility fixes for Visual Studio 2012 RTM.

If you go to the .net github repo and pull the code for [sdk_1.7.1 branch](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/sdk_1.7.1) and build it, you'll find `SharedAccessTablePolicy`. I just built this last week and have access to it via this method. Just remember to change your role references to point to your newly-built DLLs, which will show up as 1.7.1.

The namespace is `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient`:

[image]

Here's a quick screenshot from [github](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/sdk_1.7.1/microsoft-azure-api/StorageClient), of the file which now exists in 1.7.1:

[image]